# Injective mapping onto a subgroup of a finite group.

Tags: group-theory, functions, proof-verification, finite-groups

Question: Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ such that $\gcd(m,o(H))=1$. Is $\phi:H \to H$ defined by $\phi(x)=x^m$ an injective mapping?

Attempt: $\phi(x)=\phi(y) \implies x^m=y^m \implies x^my^{-m}=e \implies (y^{-1}x)^m=e$. Now, by closure, $y^{-1}x \in H$ and if $y^{-1}x\neq e$, then we must have $o(y^{-1}x) \mid m$ and $o(y^{-1}x) \mid o(H) \implies \gcd(m,o(H))>1$, a contradiction.

Injection on a finite set into itself is bijective. Hence we can regard it a permutation on $H$.

Is this correct? Kindly verify.

Comment: Looks correct. Of course at the end you meant $o(y^{-1}x)|o(H)$.

Comment: @Mark, would you please consider checking https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3339914/if-gcdog-n-oh-1-then-h-subset-n ?

Comment: Sorry, I saw the comment only now. If you assume $\gcd(m,o(H))=1$ then your solution becomes correct.

Comment: @Mark , it is regarding the link in the comment? Well, $m = o(G/N)$, so $\gcd$ is always $1$.

Comment: Yes, then it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, this is correct.

<sup>I'm posting this CW answer so that users who **confidently** concur have something to vote on, and so this question doesn't stagnate in the [Unanswered Questions Queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered). If however anyone would like to write a more substantial response to the question, please downvote this answer and post your own.</sup>